# How would one write the parametric function r=e ^cos(θ) −2cos(4θ)+sin ^5 ( θ/12) in Python?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, parametric-equations

I've tried a few formats and ideas, but the syntax is kind of confusing. Help is appreciated, danke.

[image: The function itself]

Comment: I would start with learning about Python's [arithmetic operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) and the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module. Otherwise, the main thing to keep in mind is that `sin^5(...)` is really `(sin(...))^5`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Chepner, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only with python built-in functios:

```
import math
r = math.e**(math.cos(theta)) - 2 * math.cos(4 * theta) + math.sin(theta/12)**5
```

With Sympy(for symbolic computation):

```
from sympy import Symbol, cos, sin, E
t = Symbol('Θ')
E**(cos(t)) - 2 * cos(4 * t) + sin(t/12)**5
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted because this is the only answer that suggests the `sympy` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import exp, cos, sin

theta = 0.1  # Just as an example
r = exp(cos(theta)) - 2 * cos(4 * theta) + sin(theta / 12) ** 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A very straightforward, but naive approach would be to just use the `math` library, which is a standard library in python.

```py
import math

def r(theta):
    return math.pow(math.e, math.cos(theta)) - 2 * math.cos(4*theta) + math.pow(math.sin(theta/12), 5)
```

better results are possible with libraries for scientific computing, like numpy or other members of the [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) ecosystem.

Comment: I've never ever seen that second interpretation of sin^5(x) - citation needed...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 10)
r = np.exp(np.cos(theta)) - 2*np.cos(4*theta) + np.sin(theta/12)**5

plt.plot(theta,r)
plt.savefig('parametric.jpg')
```

[image]